# How to upload File which app doesn't own and has only Uri with read permission with Retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-file, android-contentresolver

Right now when I select some file to upload from my app, for example a photo

```
private val imageFileFromGalleryPickResult =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia()) { imageUri ->
        imageUri?.let { }
    }
```

I save it to app personal storage (cache dir), which is helpful if you need to modify it (change the resolution or fix the orientation before sending to a server)

```
suspend fun savePublicFileToAppCacheDir(context: Context, fileUri: Uri): File {
    val appCacheDir = ContextCompat.getExternalCacheDirs(context)
        .filterNotNull()
        .first()
        .also { it.mkdirs() }
    val file = File(appCacheDir, "temp_file.jpg")
    context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)!!.use { input ->
        FileOutputStream(file).use { output ->
            output.write(input.readBytes())
        }
    }
    return file
}
```

After that I can easily send this file with `Retrofit2` because app owns it:

```
fun buildMultipartBodyPart(file: File, paramName: String): MultipartBody.Part {
    val requestFile = file.asRequestBody("image/jpeg".toMediaTypeOrNull())
    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(paramName, file.name, requestFile)
}

@Multipart
@POST("user/profile/photo")
suspend fun sendProfilePhoto(
    @Part photoFile: MultipartBody.Part,
)
```

But what about files which I don't copy to app's dir first, especially big size files (50mb+)?

So I have `Uri` only. How can I send the file with Retrofit then? Somehow send `InputStream`?

**Update**

I guess I can only use `fun ByteArray.toRequestBody()` for `input.readBytes()`

But again, what about big size file? :)

Answer (score 1):

For now I implemented it like this:

```
fun Uri.getFileName(
    context: Context,
    contentResolver: ContentResolver = context.contentResolver
): String? {
    val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
    contentResolver.query(this, projection, null, null, null)?.use {
        if (it.moveToFirst()) {
            return it.getString(0)
        }
    }
    return null
}

fun Uri.toMultipartBodyPart(
    context: Context,
    paramName: String
): MultipartBody.Part {
    val uri = this
    val contentResolver = context.contentResolver
    val fileName = uri.getFileName(context, contentResolver)
    val mimeType = contentResolver.getType(uri)
    val bytes = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)!!.use { input ->
        input.readBytes() // not good for RAM
    }
    val requestedBody = bytes.toRequestBody(mimeType?.toMediaTypeOrNull())
    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(paramName, fileName, requestedBody)
}
```

If there a better way, would be nice to see other answers with examples here